# Out-file a CSV-Like instead of TXT

Tags: python, pandas

I have some piece of code that write a txt file like this:

```
f2.csv,val,2
f2.csv,val,5
f2.csv,new,234
f2.csv,new,432
f2.csv,old,3
f2.csv,old,437
f2.csv,val,2
f2.csv,val,9
```

But I'd like to have something like this:

```
f2.csv,val,new,old
f2.csv,2,234,3
f2.csv,5,432,437
f2.csv,2,NaN,NaN
f2.csv,9,NaN,NaN
```

**My code:**

```
for value in df[coluna].values:
       with open(r"path\f2.csv", 'a',encoding="utf8") as filew:
           filew.write(tabela+','+coluna+','+str(value)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a built in writer:

```py
df.to_csv(open("f2.csv","w"), header=True)
```